# How can I draw a grid of squares?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My current code only draws 1 row of squares, however I want to draw a whole grid of squares? How do I do this?

```
from turtle import*

bob=Turtle()
def square():
    x = 0
    y=0
    for i in range(4):
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(50)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.goto(50+x,0)
        x+=50
    bob.goto(0,-50)
    bob.right(90)
square()
square()
square()
input()
```

Comment: PS. I called the functions that many times because i wanted the row of squares to be drawn again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to play around to understand better the concept of functions - 
the idea is that you get a function that does one simple task, and do it well - and then write other functions to combine calls to that first one with other code, to do other tasks.

Your code looks like you picked the square example from somewhere, and them just tried to pump-up the square function to do everything at once: that makes for poor quality code, which is hard to understand, or even to write correctly.

So try the following:

- A function that draws a square, and comes back to the point of start, heading the sameway
- A function that draws a square row, by repeating  "n" times: (draw a square, walk forward the square size), and them go back to the starting place.
- Another function that repeats "m" times: drawing a square row, going up one square size, heading back to the side it was originanlly facing.

---

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()

def square(side):
    for i in range(4):
        bob.forward(side)
        bob.left(90)

def row(n, side):
    for i in range(n):
        square(side)
        bob.forward(side)
    bob.penup()
    bob.left(180)
    bob.forward(n * side)
    bob.left(180)
    bob.pendown()

def row_of_rows(m, n, side):
    for i in range(m):
        row(n, side)
        bob.penup()
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(side)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.pendown()
    bob.penup()
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(m * side)
    bob.left(90)
    bob.pendown()

row_of_rows(4,5, 20)
```

Comment: Whenever I introduce functions to new programmers, I show them [lightbot](https://lightbot.com/hocflash.html). They build up the idea of procedural programming, and eventually introduce procedures as a way of reducing instruction count and repetition.

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle
loadWindow = turtle.Screen()
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.pensize(1)

STEP = 25
LENGTH = 1000
for i in range(0, LENGTH, STEP):
   turtle.penup()
   turtle.setpos(-LENGTH/2, LENGTH/2 - i)
   turtle.pendown()
   turtle.setpos(LENGTH/2, LENGTH/2 - i)
   turtle.penup()
   turtle.setpos(-LENGTH/2 + i, LENGTH/2)
   turtle.pendown()
   turtle.setpos(-LENGTH/2 + i, -LENGTH/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cdlane for suggesting integer division inside the `range` function.

```
import turtle
size = 50
for x in range(-300//size, 300//size):
    for y in range(-300//size, 300//size):
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(x * size, y * size)
        turtle.down()
        for sides in range(4):
            turtle.forward(size)
            turtle.left(90)
turtle.update()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: If you want to see how it draws then, get rid of tracer(0), update() and ht()

Comment: The OP tagged [Python-3.x] but your solution breaks under Python3 due to the floating point arguments to the `range()` function.  Simple fix is `range(-300//size, 300//size)`

Answer (score 1):

I can see why some of the answers call `hideturtle()` at the beginning of the code, instead of at the end, as well as `tracer(0)`, as that is some of the most painful to watch drawing I've ever seen.  I feel part of the fun of turtle graphics is watching the turtles, so I offer my solution:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

UNIT_SIZE, GRID_SIZE = 50, 200

def half_grid(turtle):
    speed = turtle.speed()

    for brick in range(GRID_SIZE // UNIT_SIZE):
        direction = [turtle.right, turtle.left][brick % 2 == 1]
        for i in range(0, GRID_SIZE, speed):
            turtle.forward(speed)
            yield(0)
        direction(90)
        for i in range(0, UNIT_SIZE, speed):
            turtle.forward(speed)
            yield(0)
        direction(90)

    for i in range(0, GRID_SIZE, speed):
        turtle.forward(speed)
        yield(0)

mickey = Turtle(shape='turtle')
mickey.speed(5)
mickey.up()
mickey.goto(-GRID_SIZE//2, -GRID_SIZE//2)
mickey.down()
mickey.left(90)

donnie = Turtle(shape='turtle')
donnie.speed(5)
donnie.up()
donnie.goto(GRID_SIZE//2, -GRID_SIZE//2)
donnie.down()
donnie.left(180)

generator1, generator2 = half_grid(mickey), half_grid(donnie)

while (next(generator1, 1) + next(generator2, 1) < 2):
        pass

mickey.hideturtle()
donnie.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Admittedly, you have to choose `UNIT_SIZE`, `GRID_SIZE`, and `turtle.speed()` carefully for this to work properly.

**Turtles at work:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is working :)

```
import turtle

turtle.tracer(1)  # Turns off screen updates

grid = turtle.Turtle()
STEP = 20
LENGTH = 200
for i in range(0, LENGTH+STEP, STEP):
   grid.penup()
   grid.setpos(-LENGTH/2, (LENGTH/2 - i)) # go to start hoz line possition
   grid.pendown()
   grid.setpos(LENGTH/2, (LENGTH/2 - i)) # draw horizontal line

   grid.penup()
   grid.setpos((-LENGTH/2 + i), LENGTH/2) # go to start vertical line possition
   grid.pendown()
   grid.setpos((-LENGTH / 2 + i), -LENGTH / 2)


turtle.update() 
turtle.exitonclick()
```

If you want to display instantly, change this:

```
turtle.tracer(1)  # Turns off screen updates
```

to this:

```
turtle.tracer(0)  # Turns off screen updates
```

Answer (score 0):

use two for loops to draw your grid

```
for row in range(x, width_of_screen,width_of_grid_box):
    for column in range(y,height_of_screen,height_of_grid_box):
            square = pygame.draw.rect(surface, COLOR, (row, column, width_of_grid_box, height_of_grid_box),2)
            square_pos.append(square)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj2WJ.png)

```
import turtle as t

t.tracer(0, 0)
t.speed(0)

grid={
    'left':-500,
    'right':500,
    'top':-500,
    'bottom':500,
    'interval':10
    }

x_positions=range(grid['left'],grid['right'],grid['interval'])
y_positions=range(grid['top'],grid['bottom'],grid['interval'])

for x in x_positions:
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(x,grid['top'])
    t.pendown()
    t.setpos(x,grid['bottom'])

for y in y_positions:
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(grid['left'],y)
    t.pendown()
    t.setpos(grid['right'],y)


t.update()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import turtle


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("title")
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=500, height=500)



grid = turtle.Turtle()
grid.speed(0)
grid.hideturtle()
grid.penup()
grid.goto(-240, 240)
grid.direction = "right"
grid.pendown()
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(180)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(480)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(20)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(480)
```

sorry, it's really long

Comment: It's almost like you could use some sort of loop in there somewhere.